# Helm chart deployment with spinnaker

Tags: kubernetes-helm, spinnaker

I am using spinnaker to deploy helm charts, using the stages Bake(Manifest) for creating the artifact and Deploy(Manifest) for deploying the chart.

Here i didn’t find out any option for the release name of helm install in the spinnaker stages. Even I spinned-up one helm pod in k8s cluster and tried to list out the releases. Even after successful helm chart deployment with spinnaker also, i didn't see any release name.

How to control the helm release name by using above spinnaker stages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spinnaker doesn't install helm charts using standard helm commands `helm install/upgrade`.

It takes helm chart as input, bake manifest stage transforms the chart to a single manifest file, then it applies the manifest directly to k8s in deploy manifest stage.

So, to answer your question. You can't control standard helm release name or helm chart version as k8s cluster doesn't have context of that helm chart.